# Widget crash after calling notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged due to no connection available

Tags: android, android-widget, crash, appwidgetprovider

If there is no connectioin available on the android device, my Android widget crashed when i call notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged method.

In fact, when i call this method, there is an http request to load data from server.

How i can do in order to fix this crash problem?

Here is the code of StackwidgetProvider class when i click on the "refresh" button :

```
else if (intent.getAction().equals(REFRESH_LIST_ACTION)) {

        AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        int[] ids = mgr.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, StackWidgetProvider.class));

        for(int id : ids) {
            mgr.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(id, R.id.stack_view);
        }

        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_action_lab_white;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Mise à jour des deals ..";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

        CharSequence contentTitle = "Mobideals";
        CharSequence contentText = "Mise à jour des deals terminée";
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(HELLO_ID);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Mise à jour de la liste des deals ..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

And here is the code of StackWidgetService class when my onSetDataChanged method is declared :

```
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    // This is triggered when you call AppWidgetManager notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged
    // on the collection view corresponding to this factory. You can do heaving lifting in
    // here, synchronously. For example, if you need to process an image, fetch something
    // from the network, etc., it is ok to do it here, synchronously. The widget will remain
    // in its current state while work is being done here, so you don't need to worry about
    // locking up the widget.

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        String filtre = settings.getString("filtre", "Tous");           

        HttpPost httppost = null;

        if (filtre.equals("Tous")) {
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myURL/getDeals.php");
        }

        else if (filtre.equals("Maison")) {
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myURL/getDealsMaison.php");
        }

        else if (filtre.equals("Musique")) {
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myURL/getDealsMusique.php");
        }


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connexion"+e.toString());
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parsing data
    String titre, url, site, ancienprix, nouveauprix, temperature, pseudo, categorie, dealtermine, date;

    try{
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        if (jArray.length() != 0) {
            mWidgetItems.removeAll(mWidgetItems);
        }
        JSONObject json_data=null;

        SharedPreferences setNbDeal = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        String nbDeal = setNbDeal.getString("nbDeal", "30");

        int nbDeals = Integer.parseInt(nbDeal);

        for(int i=0;i<nbDeals;i++){
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            titre=json_data.getString("titre");
            url=json_data.getString("url");
            site=json_data.getString("site");
            ancienprix=json_data.getString("ancienprix");
            nouveauprix=json_data.getString("nouveauprix");
            dealtermine=json_data.getString("dealtermine");
            temperature=json_data.getString("temperature");
            pseudo=json_data.getString("pseudo");
            categorie=json_data.getString("categorie");
            date=json_data.getString("date");

            WidgetItem currentItem = new WidgetItem(titre, url, site, ancienprix, nouveauprix, dealtermine, temperature, pseudo, categorie, date);
            mWidgetItems.add(currentItem);

        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e1){
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you preform this function in main activity?

Comment: The refresh action is done by clicking on the button on the GUI. After, the code in StackWIdgetProvider class is called and notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged method is called. Then, onSetDataChanged method is called to load the data. Maybe i will add a code in order to check there is a connexion (3g or wifi) availmable before doing the loading of the data?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why you wouldn't check to see its connected before trying to access the network.

Comment: How can i do for controlling the connexion ? Do you have an example of code?